# Diacritic Case-Insensitive search Loopback

Tags: regex, mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

Is there any way to query results on Loopback+MongoDB with Diacritic-Case-Insensitive options?

For example, If I want to search for the query `olimpic`, and the database contains words like:

```
Olímpic
olimpic
Olimpic
```

Then, all of the above should be returned as results.
I have tried with multiple queries listed below and other combinations, but nothing has worked so far.

```
{"where":{"name.text":{"like":"olimpic","options":"i"}}}
{"where":{"name.text":{"like":"/^olimpic$/i","options":"i"}}}
{"where":{"name.text":{"like":"/.*olimpic.*/i"}}}
{"where":{"name.text":{"regexp":"/.*olimpic.*/i"}}}
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?  If so, you should share it.

Comment: @dustmouse all tests have been unsuccessful. when I found the solution, I will publish it

Comment: mhergon - That's fine.  But it still doesn't hurt to show your attempt to demonstrate that you've made the effort to solve the problem.

Comment: dustmouse - I added more examples...

Comment: @mhergon for insensitive have you tried: `{"where":{"name.text":{"regexp":"/(?i).*olimpic.*/i"}}}` ?

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Yes, and return zero results. Thanks!

Comment: @mhergon You did not accept my answer, as far as I can see. Is there anything I can do to improve it so it becomes more useful to you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you want ought to be possible with [text indices](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) as of version 3.1.7 of MongoDB. Please see [SERVER-19557](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-19557) for details. Earlier versions can not deal with diacritics.

Setting up a text index is rather easy: simply create an index on all fields you want to be searched – there can be only one text index per collection:

```js
db.yourCollection.createIndex(
  {"name.text":"text","foo":"text"},
  {"default_language":"french"}
)
```

Now, to search your index, you simply do the following:

```js
db.yourCollection.find(
  { $text: {$search:"Olimpic"} }
)
```

which should give you the expected results.

hth