# Diacritic insensitive search on LoopbackJS

Tags: mongodb, loopbackjs, strongloop

This question refers to: [Diacritic Case-Insensitive search Loopback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33480431/diacritic-case-insensitive-search-loopback)

I tried to add the following indexes - `firstname` and `lastname` of my `NsUser` model like @Markus_W_Mahlberg suggested - the loopback way.

```
    {
      "name": "NsUser",
      "base": "User",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "indexes": {
        "firstname": "text" ,
        "lastname": "text"
      },
      "properties": {
        "firstname": {
          "type": "string"
        },
       "lastname": {
          "type": "string"
        }
       …
     }
     …
    }
```

I also use an auto-update script in my server.js to make sure indexes are working like suggested here: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mongodb/issues/103

My MongoDB shell version is: 3.2.3

Still it is not working. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
To answer to Pawan -
When I display my Indexes in Mongo using:

```
> db.NsUser.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "needsporty_DB.NsUser"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "text" : 1
        },
        "name" : "firstname",
        "ns" : "needsporty_DB.NsUser"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_fts" : "text",
            "_ftsx" : 1
        },
        "name" : "diatrics_insensitive_keys",
        "ns" : "needsporty_DB.NsUser",
        "weights" : {
            "firstname" : 1,
            "lastname" : 1
        },
        "default_language" : "english",
        "language_override" : "language",
        "textIndexVersion" : 3
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Syntax of declaring index in model.json file is

```
"indexes": {
     //A composite index two keys: key1 in ascending order and key2 in descending order
     "<indexName>": { "<key1>": 1, "<key2>" : -1 }
    //single field index
    "<indexName>": { "<key1>" : 1 }
   // for text indexes
   "<indexName>": { "<key1>" : "text" }   
}
```

check the  [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Model+definition+JSON+file#ModeldefinitionJSONfile-Indexes)

So change your indexes object accordingly, As a collection can have at most [one text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index), so here you need to create a compound text index with firstname and lastname i.e

```
"indexes": {
    "textSearchName" : { "firstname" : "text", "lastname" : "text" }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be working but now I get this error: "Unhandled rejection MongoError: Index with pattern: { _fts: "text", _ftsx: 1 } already exists with different options". It's strange because it's the only index I've been creating. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: can you confirm indexes by calling db.collection.getIndexes() ?

Comment: > db.collection.getIndexes() : [ ]. Seems like it returns an empty array.

Comment: Have you replaced collection with  name of your collection while getting indexes(may be you had,just confirming) i.e db.yourcollection.getIndexes(), then try . what's it returning after this ?

Comment: Shame on me... I updated the answer, if you might want to help. Thank you again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123798/discussion-between-f3l1x79-and-pawan).

Comment: you getting this error bcz you were trying to create two different text indexes on one collection, you can have only one text index docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index , to solve this create a composite text index on firstname and lastname instead of creating individual index. check edited answer .

Comment: Well indexes finally worked, but they're still diacritics sensitive with LoopbackJs' queries. Thank you anyway.